# Building a Spring-Boot Maven project with Matlab Java API dependency

Tags: java, spring, matlab, maven, spring-boot

I am building a spring boot application and using Maven for the dependencies. I need to run some Matlab code from Java and I found out that MathWorks made an official Java API available to use since 2017. But the official documentation for it only points to a `.jar` file inside installed Matlab folder and does not have any Maven dependency. So how do I add it to my project in a smart way then? Right now I just do it in my `pom.xml` like this:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.sample</groupId>
    <artifactId>sample</artifactId>
    <version>1.0</version>
    <scope>system</scope>
<systemPath>${project.basedir}/src/main/resources/yourJar.jar</systemPath>
</dependency>
```

But it seems to be a deprecated feature in Spring-Boot.

Comment: You can check at https://mvnrepository.com/ if the specified jar is available there and then specify its dependency in your pom.xml. Be careful about the version tho.

Comment: If the jar is not available in a public Maven repo you can manually install it yourself: https://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-3rd-party-jars-local.html Additionally, you can include it within the repo and install it as part of the build step.